# Python: How to change value of <scale> element in KML?

Tags: python, xml, file, google-maps, kml

I have multiple KML files that I need to change the `<scale>` value (e.g. `<scale>1.0</scale>` to `<scale>2.0</scale>`), but in python what would be the proper way of doing so?

So far only found the following info as relevant:

```
# set the coordinate precision to something smaller
In [69]: set_max_decimal_places(
   ....:             pm1,
   ....:             max_decimals={
   ....:                 'longitude': 2,
   ....:                 'latitude': 1,
   ....:             }
   ....:         )
```

and:

```
In [39]: from os import path

In [40]: kml_file = path.join( \
   ....:      '../src/pykml/test', \
   ....:      'testfiles/google_kml_developers_guide', \
   ....:      'complete_tour_example.kml')

In [44]: with open(kml_file) as f:

In [45]:     doc = parser.parse(f)
```

Comment: What have you tried and what problem are you running into with that?

Comment: What is `parser` in your 2nd code?

Comment: @har07 `from pykml import parser`

Comment: @kindall Looked around to see what would be the best method, but couldn't find any. Wondering if there is way to just locate `<scale>` and apply the change directly.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/tutorial.html#parsing-existing-kml-documents It is hard to help further given no sample XML provided in this question i.e we have no idea where `<scale>` is located within your XML doc